# how to access value of dynamic generated model in angular

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, angularjs

```
 <input type='text' ng-model='album"+$scope.i+"' />
   <h1> {{album+i}} </h1>
```

I am setting the value of ***i*** in controlller and when I inspect the textbox,
ng-model="album1" is reflected or whatever the value of i.

But now on button click in I am in need to pass this model value to some function.

Can somebody let me know, how to access this dynamic model value?

I did following patterns to access the model value:-

> {{album+i}} 
>   {{'album'+i}} 
>   {{album"+i+"}}

But none of this, is reflecting this value.
Note: this textbox+button is appened dyanmically and I have compiled textbox+button and on ng-click required function is called as well, only model value is not getting reflected.

```
$scope.appendAlbum = function()
    {

    $scope.i = $scope.i + 1;
    var tplAlbum = "<ul class='cols'> \
                        <li class='col-md-2'>\
                            <input type='text' ng-model='album"+$scope.i+"'  required /></li>\

                         <li>\
                            <a href='javascript:void(0)' ng-click='saveAlbum(album+$scope.i)' class='saveBtn' title='Click to save'> </a>\
                         </li>
                        </ul>";

    angular.element(document.getElementById('albumCols')).append(tplAlbum);
    var eleScope = $('#albumCols .cols:last').scope();
    $compile($('#albumCols .cols:last'))(eleScope);

}
```

Comment: Why not use an array to store albums?

Comment: can you provide the full code?

Comment: @AvraamMavridis Mavridis,
I have added code-snippet, please have a look..

Comment: did you tried `'... ng-click=saveAlbum("album"' + $scope.i + ') ...'` ?

Comment: change ng-click='saveAlbum(album+$scope.i)' to ng-click='saveAlbum(album"+$scope.i+")'.

Comment: @ manivannan 
Yes you are right..this way it passes the desired value..
Thank You... :)

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-model='album{{$scope.i}}' and ng-click='saveAlbum(album{{$scope.i}})'

Answer (score 0):

Update ng-click to this, will do the trick

```
<a href='javascript:void(0)' ng-click='saveAlbum(album"+$scope.i+")'> </a>\
```

> saveAlbum(album"+$scope.i+")